# Could someone introduce books or reviews on electron-electron interaction to me?

Tags: condensed-matter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Books for Condensed Matter Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22046/books-for-condensed-matter-physics)

Could someone introduce books or reviews on electron-electron interaction to me? Especially its effects on screening and transport?

Comment: Hmm... seems a bit broad of a question? An answer might be "any chemistry textbook"?

Comment: Any book on Many Body Quantum Theory will do the job. Try "Many Particle Physics" by Mahan or have a look here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22046/books-for-condensed-matter-physics

Answer (score 0):

This is a too broad topic. Feynman devotes the chapter "Interaction of several electrons" of his book on "Quantum electrodynamics" to this topic, including the derivation of the potentials and the role of the Feynman delta $\delta_{+}$.

Screening is discussed in standard statistical mechanics textbooks, which give both screened Coulomb potentials. You can this information [online](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/plasma/lectures/node7.html) as well.