# Supplements for Kittel's Solid State Physics?

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, solid-state-physics

I think by supplement I really mean replace. I spent a lot of time agonizing over the first chapter of Kittel as he introduces a bunch of concepts such as Bravais lattice and he doesn't clearly define them. It's frustrating and infuriating considering that I have no background in crystallography nor solid state physics, and as an introduction to the subject I haven't found the book to be very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22046/2451

Answer (score 0):

The only other books I can personally recommend would be Ashcroft and Mermin, Solid State Physics, or Chaikin and Lubensky, Principles of Condensed Matter Physics. Both books are more advanced than Kittel.

Good luck and don't give up! Sometimes a chemistry book may help. 
-D

Comment: I absolutely agree with Dylan. I found Ashcroft and Mermin much better than Kittel when I was reading. One other more engineering oriented (device) first-read (a simpler read) could be the book: Semiconductor device fundamentals by Robert Pierret. And finally the book by Ziman will be a great next step from Mermin.

Comment: Condensed Matter Physics by Marder may also interest you, but I think his section on crystallography is tiny.