# Good introduction to many-body Green's function via path integral formulation?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, path-integral, many-body

Can anyone kindly provide any information on valuable references or books on this topic? It appears to be prevalent in 90s papers on High-$T_c$ superconductivity or quantum Hall effect, especially in a form of fermions interacting with $U(1)$ gauge field.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22046/2451 and links therein.