# Fermi Liquid Theory Reference

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, fermi-liquids

I am trying to study [Fermi liquid theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_liquid_theory) as a primer to understand what so-called non-Fermi liquids are. In particular, I want to understand the predictions of Fermi liquid theory (such as temperature dependence of observables), how they are derived, and when they are/aren't applicable. It would be particularly nice, though not necessary, if all these results were tabulated in some nice fashion as well. Are there any good resources out there for introductions to Fermi liquid theory?

Comment: Many of the books [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22046/books-for-condensed-matter-physics) should have a chapter on Fermi liquid theory.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry if I'm a little late with responding, but I'll give you what I have on the subject (in no particular order):

**Online Reviews**

1. Michael Cross' Fermi Liquid [Principles](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/~mcc/Ph127/c/Lecture9.pdf), [Thermodynamics](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/~mcc/Ph127/c/Lecture10.pdf), and [Collective Modes](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/~mcc/Ph127/c/Lecture11.pdf): A good first step into the physics of Fermi liquid theory. Simple and easily understood.
2. Dupuis' [Intro to Fermi Liquid Theory](http://www.lptmc.jussieu.fr/files/chap_fl.pdf): More advanced than Cross' introduction, with a good discussion of the microscopics of Fermi liquid theory
3. T. Giamarchi's notes on [Interactions in Quantum Fluids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1030). Amazing intro with great description of many-body interactions in fermi liquids and beyond. Good description of when and where fermi liquid fails.
4. [Fermi-liquid theory: Life-time of single-particle
   excitations from LMU Munich.](https://www.physik.uni-muenchen.de/lehre/vorlesungen/wise_14_15/heidrich-meisner_solid-state/schedule/fermi_liquid.pdf) Only three pages long, but good microscopic derivation of quasiparticle lifetime in Fermi liquid theory.
5. Ivanov's [Intro to Fermi Liquid Theory](https://people.phys.ethz.ch/~ivanov/cmt/1213/ssth-lecture9.pdf). Short, but good reference on some simple concepts. What it does explain, it does *very* well.
6. Landau's [Intro to Fermi Liquid Theory](http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~jarrell/COURSES/SOLID_STATE/Chap6/chap6.pdf). Note that, though this is not be *the* Landau, it is a solid intro to the basics. Excellent discussion of the thermodynamics behind Fermi liquid theory.
7. Patankar's [Intro to Landau-Fermi Liquid Theory.](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~shreyas/fermi_liquids.pdf) Good microscopic description. Explains the breakdown of the Fermi liquid theory near the end.
8. Andy Schofield's [Intro to Non-Fermi Liquids.](http://physics.gu.se/~tfkhj/QuantumMatter/Schoefield.pdf) Good, quick intro to Fermi liquid fundamentals and where it fails.
9. H.J. Schulz, G. Cuniberti, P. Pieri. [Fermi liquids and Luttinger liquids](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9807366). Self-contained intro to Fermi liquid theory and Luttinger liquids. Great intro on the more advanced side.
10. Sunkai's [Intro to the Fermi Liquid](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~sunkai/teaching/Winter_2013/chapter06.pdf). Very detailed description of Fermi liquid theory, especially the microscopic description.
11. Thuneberg's [Introduction to Landau’s Fermi Liquid Theory](https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=52ed22c7cf57d7575f8b45ee&assetKey=AS%3A272427517448201%401441963190164). Short but amazing introduction to the main points of the theory.

**Ph.D. Theses**

12. Kelly Elizabeth Reidy's [Fermi Liquids near Pomeranchuk Instabilities](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=kent1406286277&disposition=inline). Great introduction to the theory of Fermi liquid basics and its instabilities.

**Books**

13. Philippe Nozieres, David Pines. [The Theory of Quantum Liquids.](https://books.google.com/books?id=q3wCwaV-gmUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) This is *the* book on Fermi liquid theory. One of the authoritative texts  on the subject. Two Volumes.
14. Lev Davidovich Landau, Evgeniĭ Mikhaĭlovich Lifshitz, and Lev Petrovich Pitaevsk. [Statistical Physics: Theory of the condensed state](https://books.google.com/books?id=NaB7oAkon9MC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). From the celebrated Landau and Lifshitz Course of Theoretical Physics. Includes a discussion of Fermi liquid physics you can't find anywhere else.
15. Abrikosov, Gorkov, and Dzyaloshinki. [Methods of Quantum Field Theory in Statistical Physics.](https://books.google.com/books?id=E_9NtwNY7UcC&source=gbs_similarbooks) By far one of the best books available on the microscopic theory of the Fermi liquid. Very, very advanced.
16. Fetter and Walecka. [Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems.](https://books.google.com/books?id=t5_DAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=quantum%20theory%20of%20many-particle%20systems&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy8uWLmcbUAhWMHD4KHR2yDNUQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=quantum%20theory%20of%20many-particle%20systems&f=false) Like Abrikosov et. al., this book focuses on the microscopics and is a reasonably advanced text.
17. Piers Coleman. [Introduction to Many-Body Physics.](https://books.google.com/books?id=ESB0CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=coleman&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM4cW7mcbUAhXKaD4KHVzOBoAQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=coleman&f=false) A relatively new text, the chapter on Fermi liquids is unparalleled. A soon-to-be classic in the field.
18. Gerald Mahan. [Many-Particle Physics.](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFDUBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=mahan%20many%20body&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicpNfjmcbUAhXJZj4KHZCYAawQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=mahan%20many%20body&f=false) A classic introduction to the microscopics of Fermi liquids and many-body physics. Personally, I am not a fan of their notation, but still a good reference nonetheless.

Let me know if you need more, but these are the main references I turn to when I need help understanding Fermi liquid theory.