# Feynman diagrams: from QFT to condensed matter

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, many-body

I studied Feynman diagrams in quantum field theories and I'm going to study them in the context of condensed matter physics.
  In this post [Books for Condensed Matter after Ashcroft/Mermin](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22046/), two books are suggested in particular for this topic

1. A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many Body Problem by Richard Mattuck;
2. Feynman Diagram Techniques in Condensed Matter Physics by Radi A. Jishi.

Any other suggestion about books or lectures notes on Feynman diagrams  in condensed matter physics?
Are there books or lectures notes that someway discuss similarities and differences of Feynman diagrams tecniques in QFT and condensed matter physics?

Comment: By QFT, do you mean "relativistic QFT"? Because there are several good books about 'QFT in condensed matter physics' or 'condensed matter field theory' (often called many-body theory). Usually they discuss Feynman diagram techniques, but do not focus on them.

Comment: @Anyon Yes, relativistic QFT, e.g. Standard Model. Which books?

Comment: particularly for feynman diagrams i recommend henrik bruss intro to many body physics, apart from that in general qft i recommend altland and simons

Comment: If u would like to understand how Feynman diagrams appear in CM and how to deal with, I will recommend "Condensed Matter Field Theory" by Altland et al. Also u can try to find English edition (I do not know about it) of Levitov & Shitov "Green functions"  which contains a lot of problems and examples of FeynDiag in CM

Comment: Roughly speaking, there is no difference. In CM you work with euclidean action which can be obtained from the Minkowskian by analytical continuation, i.e. Wick rotation. In flat space you can always perform (may be this statement is not tottaly correct) Wick rotation and obtain field theory for CM