# Books/Resrouces for learning Feynman Diagrams? (Ideally in the context of condensed matter)

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams

As the title says, I am looking for a good resource or book to teach myself Feynman Diagrams.

I am a graduate student doing experimental condensed matter, and recently I have been struggling with some concepts that seem to most always be explained with Feynman Diagrams, which I can't read.  With the lab shut down for COVID-19, I figure I have between two and eighteen months to teach myself, but I have found very few (good) resources.

In short, to try to make this as specific as possible, I am looking for a resource that:

> Is suitable for an experimentalist at the graduate level.  If there is an undergraduate level book, I would love that, too.
>
> Requires as little theoretical background (e.g. QFT) as possible
>
> Ideally contextualizes to condensed matter as much as possible
>
> Has examples and exercises

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The classic gentle condensed matter intro to Feynman diagrams is Mattuck's "A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many-Body Problem". Lots of examples and exercises, and phrased in the clearest, simplest language possible.

Comment: My go-to recommendation is Gerald Mahan's "Many Particle Physics". It is entirely written within the context of condensed matter. It is very detailed, quite technical, and some people find it tedious. On the up side - he doesn't leave any stone unturned

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22046/books-for-condensed-matter-after-ashcroft-mermin