# Book as supplement to Fradkin's "Field Theories of Condensed Matter Physics"

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, field-theory, education

I am trying to read Fradkin's book "Field Theories of Condensed Matter Physics" but I am finding it to be a bit hard to follow at some places. In particular, I find that Fradkin sometimes throws some formulas out of nowhere and while I can work through most of them, some are too difficult for me to understand/derive. I was thus wondering what books would you recommend as a supplement to it.

I know of Altland and Simon's "Condensed Matter Field Theory" and Shankar's "Quantum Field Theory and COndensed Matter Physics" but the former is as advanced as Fradkin's book (from a first impression--but I could be wrong) and the latter is way simpler than Fradkin's book.

Any recommendations are appreciated.

**EDIT:** The things that I mostly want to cover from Fradkin's book is sigma models, topological terms, topological phases, gauge theories in condensed matter, quantum hall effects from the perspective of field theory, quantum entanglement. I need a book that implements the theory of Lie groups/algebras and representations to make things more formal (but a book written for physicists). Obviously, the supplementary book need not include all these topics.

Comment: The topic _is rather advanced_ you know, so you would expect textbooks on the matter to be advanced as well ;) We used Atland and Simons, but I would recommend Bruus and Flensberg's Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics. It is a very pedagogical presentation while also treating some heavy topics like Matsubara sums. But try to get the newest version, many errors have been corrected.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thanks for the comment. I have checked out your suggestion, but I can see that it's written mostly in second quantization language, whereas Fradkin uses a lot of path integrals. Also, there's almost no mention of gauge fields (apart from the superconductivity chapter).

Comment: Maybe Nagaosa's Quantum Field Theory in Condensed Matter Physics could help fill in some gaps. It mostly uses path integrals, but is a lot more limited in scope, so it might depend on what parts of Fradkin you have trouble with.

Comment: @Anyon Will check it out, thank you. It does seem to be very limited in scope, but could prove helpful.

Comment: I think Piers Coleman's textbook *Introduction to Many-Body Physics* is really good for the level you're aiming at.

Comment: Note for later: Please flag for book sticker when bounty has expired.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22046/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I do not think it's a duplicate of that question, since I am asking for a supplement to Fradkin's book, which has a very specific approach. As per the previous comments, a book such as Pier Coleman's could also be considered as a book to be used after Ashcroft & Mermin but it has little in common with Fradkin's.

Comment: One book you might wish to check: Quantum Field Theory for Many-Body Systems by Xiao Gang Wen. The text is sufficiently lucid enough.

Comment: Actually, this really depends on the topics you want to cover. Do you have a rough list of important topics in mind? Fradkin covers a lot of things...