# Books on Condensed Matter after reading Messiah's Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, education

What are some good books on Condensed Matter physics that will be accessible after reading Messiah (both volumes)? With no prior background in Condensed Matter, and that explain concepts in an understandable manner.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22046/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Atland's book [https://www.amazon.com/Condensed-Matter-Theory-Alexander-Altland/dp/0521769752](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521769752) as a modern introduction to the field of Consended Matter with applications of QFT. It contains rather a broad recap and crash course on variational calculus and QM, and then discusses the Green Function's techniques, Finite Temperature Theory, Superconductivity, phenomena in disordered systems and non-equilibrium statistical physics in the end.

And the classical reference is the Mahan's book - Many-Particle Physics: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780306463389. It is devoted to collective phenomena in quantum systems.